# errno: -4066 problem in next.js app creation

Tags: next.js

During Installation next app i got that error:

C:\Marcin\coding\Projekt16>npx create-next-app @latest
Could not create a project called "@latest" because of npm naming restrictions:
* name can only contain URL-friendly characters

C:\Marcin\coding\Projekt16>npx create-next-app
√ What is your project named? ... form
√ Would you like to use TypeScript with this project? ... No / Yes
√ Would you like to use ESLint with this project? ... No / Yes
√ Would you like to use `src/` directory with this project? ... No / Yes
√ Would you like to use experimental `app/` directory with this project? ... No / Yes
√ What import alias would you like configured? ... @/dada/*
Creating a new Next.js app in C:\Marcin\coding\Projekt16\form.

Using npm.

Installing dependencies:

- react
- react-dom
- next
- @next/font
- typescript
- @types/react
- @types/node
- @types/react-dom
- eslint
- eslint-config-next

added 270 packages, and audited 271 packages in 32s

102 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

Initializing project with template: default

Aborting installation.
Unexpected error. Please report it as a bug:
[Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'C:\Marcin\coding\Projekt16\form\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\is-docker\package.json'] {
errno: -4066,
code: 'EMFILE',
syscall: 'open',
path: 'C:\Marcin\coding\Projekt16\form\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\is-docker\package.json'
}

C:\Marcin\coding\Projekt16>

Trying in cmd and VS terminal - the same effect. Using Windows 10, node version 18.13. Anybody have idea what's going on?

errno:-4066

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo in your create next app command. Try removing the space between 'app' and '@'.
Or use this 'npx create-next-app@latest'.

Comment: no, it dosn't matter how I wrote it. Effect is  the same. But thanks for the idea!

Answer (score -1):

try disabling your window's security.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34876512)